# Instead of receipt, can a bank statement be used as evidence for expense tax deduction?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, irs

I'm new to tax returns as well as this site. I'm filling my tax returns, and last year I've been taking lunch at this restaurant. I don't have the receipts but the charge is listed in my bank statement. Will that work?

The question is in more context of producing evidence in case of audit. I don't have the receipt but if I show them my bank statement to back it up, will that work?

Comment: As it’s written, the question is unclear. Can you please return and edit to clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: edited, please ask me more question if it's not clear, as I'm new here

Comment: what are you claiming this under? is this an employee expense or a business expense?

Comment: I'm claiming this as meal/coffee expenses work from home as an employee. I also have taxi/uber expenses

Comment: The question "Will that work?" is totally ambiguous.  What does that mean?  Did you write off lunch?  How? In most cases, your lunch is not a deductible expense.

Comment: Meals, while working, are only a deduction if it was in the context of a business meeting.

Comment: You might also want to spell out some more of your background. Are you a W-2 employee? Or a 1099 self-employed individual?

Comment: I'm a W-2 employee. Will that work means is that deductible and acceptable when submitting tax returns. So I understand my lunch is not deductible but if it's with someone in context of business then it's deductible?

Comment: @App2015 if you are a W-2 employee, you are not a business in the eyes of the IRS.  As such you cannot have any kind of business expenses.  You may be able to deduct some unreimbursed expenses if you itemize, but individual meals are not included there.

Comment: You say you are a W-2 employee, but work from home. Do you work from the room that can be considered a home-office? I E, there is nothing else going on in that room it is not your bedroom a guestroom etc. it is 100% used to conduct business.

Comment: @PeteB. I understand, so I'll not include any meals or transportation expenses.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm a software guy and I have my computer desk and TV (for video trainings/learnings) with sofa in my studio apartment (370 sq ft), and of course I've my bed in the same area. Kitchen and bathroom additional, I'm confused on what percentage to put for office/room and how do I work out my `rent`, `electricity`, `internet` and `phone` bill against for the business use. I work solely for this company spending almost 10-12 hours between work and study (for work) every day.

Comment: I suggest you read https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/home-office-deduction - As I read it, I don't see how you can take the home office deduction. Other members may differ in my interpretation.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer so you mean as a w-2 employee if I work 100% from home, I can't take the home office deduction? I also spent around 20K on computer equipment, tablets, phones and furniture in 2017.

Comment: From the linked IRS pub, I don't see how you can claim an area that's just for business use. The equipment is different. As a W2 employee, why are you responsible for your own equipment?

Comment: The company doesn't buy tablets, phones etc. it's like BYOD (bring your own device) I had a desktop at office but I moved to home to be able to study and work without distractions, noise level is high at the office. As a result I had to buy all the equipment. TV is not for entertainment, it's for the Apple TV apps android tv apps etc. and learning from online video training providers. It was a huge expense, they don't buy it for me but let me work from home so I want to claim this expense on my tax returns.

Comment: they couldn't offer me a separate room, so it's actually for the convenience of the employer that they let me work from home. https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3335323-how-do-i-report-a-home-office-for-my-w-2-income-how-do-i-assess-what-i-can-deduct-for-working-from-home

Comment: @App2015 my advice would be to see an accountant.  You have a some large misconceptions about deductions and that person can educate you and go over how to minimize your taxes.  The education you receive will be worth the small fee paid.  I say accountant, not a drone from a well known tax service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Employees can't deduct ordinary commuting from your home, or meals taken before, during or after the workday.   There is an exception if you are *traveling* but the litmus test there is that where you sleep that night is a significant distance from your home.  There is also an exception for lunches which are bona-fide business meetings, but this is so widely abused that IRS has picayune rules to keep you from gaming that exception, and they can bite you at audit time.

Office space needs to be an exclusive room used only for office.  As far as equipment, you can't deduct equipment that is *dual-use* -- work and also non-work (being a student is non-work unless it's an employer-required course). It needs to pass a "duck test" -- does it look, walk and quack like this is exclusively for work?   That can be hard to do in tight quarters.

Suppose you're a draftsman and you own an expensive 42" plotter "for work".  But your model railroad room is lined with intricate drawings of model trains obviously printed out on that same 42" plotter.  Whoops.

Also, expensive equipment needs to be *depreciated* - you can't buy a $3000 PC and then boom, take $3000 off your taxes in year 1.  Weird, I know.

Generally, if you are getting inventive about how to take deductions, IRS staff and Congress *has already been* inventive about catching that particular scheme.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer. In context of trainings, these are not college degree etc. so I'm not a full time student but I do these trainings to meet the demands of the work.

Comment: for the computer and other equipment, I'm using turbo tax and it's calculating all the depreciation automatically.

Comment: My office space is not an exclusive room, it's a studio and I've allocated portion of it towards my work but I've measured the area taken up by my desk, chair, side table, tv (for work - app development, trainings, presentations) and book stand.

Comment: @app in such close quarters, it's tough.  Do a "mock court" on the matter, but don't "Mary Sue" the narrative to suit yourself, earnestly play both sides, e.g. think like the IRS agent would.  You'll need to know the applicable IRS guidance so read it all, and it helps to follow IRS case law.  If in doubt IRS tends to decide in their own favor and say "sue us, here's how". Which I have done successfully.